# Can fluent English speakers distinguish between “steel”, “still”, and “steal”?

Tags: pronunciation, spoken-english, phonetics, vowels, homophones

Can fluent English speakers understand this sentence the first time they hear it?

> What? They still steal steel?

Can they hear a difference between the pronunciation of the words still, steal, and steel?

Comment: Not that it should be relied upon as a holy grail - but this website can be fairly useful for ELL to find the homophones of a word: https://www.homophone.com/search?type=&q=steal (the main downside, is it shows no result if the word has no homophones in their dictionary)

Comment: Only context will tell you if steel or steal is the way to go. still is not the same sound: /i/

Answer (score 81):

Still (/stɪl/) and steel (/sti:l/) are distinguishable. The vowel sounds in these two words are different.

Steal and Steel (/sti:l/) are homophones and are pronounced exactly the same.

However, the words are, in this case, easily identified by grammar. In this sentence, "steal" is a verb and "steel" is a noun. "Steel" as a verb cannot take "steal" (as a noun) as its object. So there is no ambiguity in the sentence.

Comment: "Steel" can be used as a verb -- "To steel oneself to make the decision". More rarely "steal" can be used as a noun: *The Big Steal* was a book title not long ago. But yes, "steel" is typically a noun and "steal" a verb.

Comment: @DavidSiegel: Steel: to coat with said metal.

Comment: @DavidSiegel Steel as a noun is an uncountable noun and can be used as-is. Steal as a noun is countable and requires a determiner such as "a" or "the" or to be pluralised. It would be "They still steel a steal?" (nonsensical but grammatically correct)

Comment: I would say a native speaker, depending on accent, could distinguish steal and steel. To my ear, the "ee" sound in "steel" is longer.

Comment: @MattThrower: I disagree with your comment both as a matter of fact and as a matter of logic.  U.S. English is my first language (and, FWIW, essentially my only one) and I agree with the three answers, which say that “steal” and “steel” are homophones.  I pronounce them exactly the same, so there’s no way anybody could distinguish which one I’m saying.  And, if I heard somebody say two words that were distinguishable from each other (but different from “still”), without context, I wouldn’t know which was which.

Comment: In my corner of the UK, "steal" has a slight hint of a diphthong in the vowel. "steel" does not. But I wouldn't expect a non-native speaker to hear the difference.

Comment: @Scott I'm British. And, as alephzero suggests, in RP I believe there's a very slight difference.

Comment: I'm a west-coast American. When I say the words "steal" and "steel", it feels like the vowel in the latter is further forward. I don't know whether anyone could hear that minor difference. "Still" is completely distinguishable.

Comment: @alephzero as an aside Cambridge dictionary has the same pronunciation for both as does Oxford. Though I was only looking at the online version of both.

Comment: -1, I really think to be a complete answer this should note that in some regions there **is** a subtle difference between **steal** and **steel**. It would be fine to say that this difference is unimportant for English learners and that some people may be unable to distinguish.

Comment: @MattThrower - That's exactly why I don't like to see answers flatly state that two words are homophones. Nuances of the pronunciation of vowels [are *very* regional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_close_front_vowels), even with people who would hotly insist they speak some kind of "standard" dialect.

Comment: ee/ea are the same sound.

Answer (score 38):

Context is the key to understanding. If your reader or conversation partner understands you are talking about someone or something with a habit of misappropriating steel, then it is perfectly reasonable to say they *still steal steel* or *steal steel still*. If they do not have that context, they you may need to explain it.

Most native speakers of English will pronounce *steal* and *steel* identically, but differently from *still*. Some people in Yorkshire might pronounce all three differently, and some people in Tennessee might pronounce all three the same.

---

In all the "standard" accents with which I am familiar, *steel* and *steal* are homophones, both pronounced /stiːl/. The spelling of *steal* and words like *team* and *cream* among others reflects a distinction in pronunciation which was mostly lost by the 18th century in what is known as the [*meet*-*meat* merger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_close_front_vowels#Meet%E2%80%93meat_merger). The distinction is preserved only in some corners of Ireland and Northern England, and I would say a learner should not bother with it.

The standard pronunciation of *still* has a shorter vowel, thus /stɪl/. That said, many speakers of Southern, Appalachian, and African-American Englishes, and what is called Estuary English, speak with what is called the [*fill*-*feel* merger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_vowel_changes_before_historic_/l/#Fill%E2%80%93feel_merger). Pairs like *ill* and *eel*, *hill* and *heal*, or *will* and *we'll* are pronounced the same in those accents.  Again, I would say a learner is safest sticking to the standard pronunciation in speaking.

Comment: I'm curious what distinction is made in Yorkshire between "steal" and "steel".

Comment: Indeed, some speakers of Cockney/Estuary English merge all four of  _ill_, _eel_, _hill_ and _heal_ into /iw/.

Comment: There are times where I'll pronounce *will* and *we'll* the same - e.g. in "Will we go soon?" "Yes, we'll go soon", *will* and *we'll* are indistinguishable.

Comment: @BobJarvis: May I ask (roughly) where you live?   (I’m on the East Coast of the US, and I guess I would understand your speech, aided by context, but I would not speak that way myself, and I would not consider it correct.)

Comment: Would you say that “we’ll” and “wheel” are homophones? (I realize that there may be regional variations.)

Comment: @chepner Answer from a native Yorkshire speaker: the vowel in "steal" has a trace of a diphthong in it. Imagine the pronunciation of "sequel" without the "kw" sound in the middle (and without replacing it with a glottal stop, or whatever) and you get close to the Yorkshire pronunciation of "seal". (But this is a mild vowel shift compared with some others in South Yorkshire dialects, where "coal" and "hole" both rhyme with "oil"!)

Comment: I think you need a general rule. No one seems to be providing that. Regional differences are a separate chapter. You first have to deal with minimal pairs and graphemes.

Comment: @alephzero is this the difference? [Mid front unrounded vowel /eː/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid_front_unrounded_vowel) v.s. [Close front unrounded vowel /iː/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_front_unrounded_vowel)?

Comment: @scott I would say that we'll is more we-ul and wheel is more wee-el.  I am in (old) Hampshire in the UK with a Yorkshire father, a Surrey month and lots of time spent in the Devon area.  Mi accent ain't dat neat.

Answer (score 5):

I, for one, hear a significant difference between "still" and "steal" or "steel". I would call the vowel sound that I make, and typically hear, in "still" a "short-I", while I would call the vowel sound in "steal" or "steel" a "long-e". There are, I am sure, more technically correct terms for these sounds. To help clarify, to me "Still" rhymes with "hill" and "kill", while "steal" rhymes with "keel", "feel", and "conceal".

As is implied by the forgoing, to me "steal" and "steel" are homophones, with no detectable difference in sound.

Comment: There isn't much mention of "still" in these answers, perhaps because it is the most easily distinguished of the three. I think it's worth pointing out that one of the characteristics of a typical non-native accent is the way the short **i** in **still** is frequently mis-pronounced. The name "Philip" is not "Pheeleep", a **pill** is not **peel** and so on.

Comment: But to non-English natives who struggle distinguishing "still" and "steel", they will also not distinguish between "keel" and "kill". So your explanation "still rhymes with kill" is not useful.

Answer (score 3):

Can fluent English speakers understand the sentence?

> What? They still steal steel?

Well, certainly yes. We use our knowledge of everyday English to make a rational interpretation of the likely meaning of the sentence. In this sense, pronunciation is not key.

Can fluent English speakers distinguish these words when spoken in isolation, with no context? I could certainly attempt to pronounce each word with such emphasis to make each one sound unique and probably identifiable to many people. Would I do that in normal speech? Probably not.

Comment: Just wait till they see the Buffalo sentence.  :P  Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo.

Answer (score 1):

"What? They still steal steel?"

Yes, "still" has a different sound to "steel" and "steal". We use our knowledge of general sentence order to logically work this out.

Also, the emphasis placed on each of these words in a question would allow us to understand that "steal" is the verb, and that "steel" is the noun. More emphasis may be placed on "steal" because the sentence is interrogative.

However, I understand that this is something hard for non-native English speakers. I have heard these three words pronounced as the same word many a time by non-native speakers. It is like "fill" and "feel". The only way you can get better at this is by listening to a native English pronunciation and practising.

Comment: In some areas steal is pronounced more like stale not quite the same but approaching it. Therefore you have 3 different pronunciations for the three words. But most southerners would not recognise that and probably have never seen anyone "nail on a bag of kneels"

Answer (score 0):

**In English, the difference in speech between steel/steal and still is called a minimal pair.**

ae/ee are  pronounced the same way. It is their graphemes (how they are written) that differ.

**still** is pronounced differently. That  said, there is only one sound difference between steel/steal and still.

[minimal pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_pair)

In English, minimal pairs (how you pronounce vowel sounds and not how they are written) are very important because

still contains the sound  /ɪ/ for the i.
steal/steel contain the sound [i:] for ea and ee.

The difference between steal and steel in spoken language will come from **the co-text**.

- This seat is as hard as steel.
- To steal is not a good thing.

The sounds in steel/steal and still are never misheard by native speakers in this sense.
And still is an adverb. So, a totally different category.

It is important to do exercises with minimal pairs in order to become used to them. English has many quirks but knowing usual minimal pairs helps learners as how English sounds is not how it is written.

bat/bet
steal/steel [we saw this one], others include: feet and feat
hot/hit
but/bat
bait/late....notice: ai and a are both the same sound.

The most difficult one is probably the /ɪ/. The sounds of the i and u in the word minute (for time) are both /ɪ/.  Also, the /ɪ/ does not exist in some languages like French and Spanish. So those speakers have a hard time with: sheet/ship.

Etc. There are tons of places online and in books to learn these sounds. Please note: there are regional variations sometimes.

At this level of learning, I think regional differences should be left out of explanations because it is already hard enough to grasp the idea of minimal pairs and graphemes in English.

Here's a great book on minimal pairs for intermediate and advanced students:

[image: English Pronunciation Illustrated by Trim]

```
That book really is a good way to learn pronunciation in English.
```

It is for British English, but, no matter, it can be adapted to American English, too.

Comment: I'm confused by your list of pairs. bat/bet, hot/hit and but/bat differ in single vowel sounds, and bait/late differs only in initial consonant sound, but surely sheen/neat differ in _both_ initial and final consonant sounds?

Comment: I had an error. But the minimal pair sound difference between bait and late is correct. ai and a are the same sound here.

Comment: The list above includes both pairs of homonyms (is standard dialects) such as  steal/steel  and feet/feat. These are **not** minimal pairs. Others in the list, such as but/bat **are**. This should be corrected if this answer is to have value.

Comment: The Wikipedia article in the above answer says: "and minimal pair drills were [in the 1940s and 1950s] widely used to train students ...However, later writers have criticized the approach as being artificial and lacking in relevance to language learners' needs." I tend to agree with the "later writers" and think it would be best to omit "minimal pairs" from answers here -- i do not see that they are of direct use to learners, although they may inform teaching methods, such as by knowing sounds or distinctions  not found in some learner's native languages.

Comment: On the other hand, i think that mention of alternate dialects **should** often be included in answers here, because learners **will** encounter at least the more common ones, and may encounter others. Learners of US English will surely encounter Southern and Western accents, and may encounter what is soemtiems called "African American Vernacular" and dialects spoken by those of Hispanic background. UK learners will surely encounter several variations besides RP, although I am not knowledgeable enough about BrE to be sure which (Cockney??)

Comment: @DavidSiegel I really do not care what some silly Wikipedia article claims. If you don't learn minimal pairs - directly or indirectly - you'll never learn English. Minimal pairs are incredibly useful. In fact, they teach them to kids in school. It is very difficult to master the fact that many vowel sounds have the same materialization with different letters: minute. The i and u are the same sound. //**steel/steal** and **still** are a minimal pair.  [i:] for steel/steal versus /i/ for still. **steel versus still** and **steal versus still**.

Comment: You don't teach regional dialects before teaching standard ones. In standard British and American English: steel, steal and still are all pronounced the same way. In fact, even in Black English they are the same. Let's leave Hispanics out of this,shall we? That is really beyond the pale. This is not a Phd course in pronunciation variations. The only way to show students the oddities of English is to at some point introduce the sound system of English. I wonder, have you actually ever taught English??

Comment: Why not Chinese speakers or Haitian Creole speakers? Hm?

Comment: I am sorry but it is simply untrue that "In standard British and American English: steel, steal and still are all pronounced the same way." I have yet to hear a standard speaker who pronounces "steel" and  "still" identically.  Learners need not master regional variations, but need to know that they exist, because they **will** hear them.

Comment: The Wikipedia statement disfavoring Minimal pairs in teaching is cited to Brown, Gillian (1990). *Listening to Spoken English*. pp. 144–6. Do you consider that a reliable source? I should add that I have never before heard of "minimal pairs" and consider that I know English fairly well.

Comment: @DavidSiegel **OMG, are you misreading me on purpose**?? Steal/steel are pronounced the same way on both sides of the Atlantic and so is still. I spent considerable time making clear: steel/steal, one sound. still another sound. How can you have read everything I have written and misread me like that?? The difference in either is precisely: steel/steal VERSUS still. For pete's sake...

Comment: Yes you said earlier that "steel" and "still" sounded different, and seemed to contradict yourself.  If what you meant was that there is no difference between BrE and AmE for any of the three words, that is probably true, but i don't think it is what you wrote, and differences between BrE and AmE were not the point of the immediately previous comments, so I did not take your comment as meaning that. I am surely not intentionally misreading you nor misrepresenting your comments --  i may will have misunderstood you.

Comment: I will repeat this one last time: steal/steel have the same phoneme. still has another. That difference is the same in standard speech in the English language. It is exactly what I wrote in my answer. "**still contains the sound /ɪ/ for the i. steal/steel contain the sound [i:] for ea and ee**" I am not contradicting myself.  You did not read my answer carefully. It's there in black and white.

Comment: @Lambie You still have non-minimal pairs in your list of minimal pairs.  Feet and feat are not a minimal pair.  Nor are steel and steal though I hope you were implying 2 minimal pairs there (still and steal as a pair, and still and steel as the other).  
Learning to distinguish the pairs... is not the most useful thing for a learner unless there is no context (which isn't common in practice).  It's not useless, but I think there are usually more important things to spend time on.

Comment: @ttbek I never said feat and feet are minimal pairs. I said that ea and ee are pronounced the same way in in steal/steel AND those two words VERSUS still (steal/still and steel/still) are minimal pairs.

Comment: "It is important to do exercises with minimal pairs in order to become used to them. English has many quirks but knowing usual minimal pairs helps learners as how English sounds is not how it is written."  You imply the following list are minimal pairs.  If that is instead meant to be a list of words that sound the same, then it is still wrong (the other 3 do NOT sound the same).

Comment: @You are misreading ME. In the UK and in the US, **steal/steel** are pronounced the same way. In the UK and US, **still** is pronounced the same way. steal/still and steel/still are minimal pairs. Or my shorthand version: steal/steel versus still are minimal pairs. Of course, they do need exercises. You have to condition your brain to bit/beet, especially if you are a French, Portuguese or Spanish speaker, for example, otherwise you risk calling  **a ship in the harbor**  **a sheep** in the harbor, which many would.